# Significati di "ridicolo"

Tags: english-comparison, adjectives, word-meaning

Mi ha colpito l'uso dell'aggettivo "ridicolo" nella versione italiana del film "Django Unchained".

Quando Dr Schultz parla di far affari con il signor Candie dice che intende offrire ***una cifra ridicola***.  Secondo il dizionario Oxford, "ridiculous" in inglese significa *very silly or unreasonable* e viene riportato l'esempio "They ate and drank a ridiculous amount", dove è chiaro che "ridiculous" corrisponde ad "esagerato", "enorme".

Il dizionario Treccani, oltre al significato di "che fa ridere, degno di derisione, perché strano o goffo o insulso", riporta il significato "di scarsa entità o valore, insignificante, esiguo, meschino: *mi è costato una somma r.*; *stipendio ridicolo*."  In pratica, l'opposto del significato che l'aggettivo può avere in inglese.

Si tratta dell'ennesimo caso in cui, per seguire l'inglese, abbiamo coniato un'espressione che italiana non è? Mi viene in mente il verbo *realizzare* che così spesso trovo utilizzato per tradurre *to realize*, quando dovrebbe essere usato il verbo *rendersi conto*. Oppure esiste in italiano un significato dell'aggettivo "ridicolo" che ricalca l'uso inglese?

Comment: È uno dei tanti falsi amici: stessa etimologia, significati a volte in parte sovrapponibili, ma spesso completamente diversi (*meretricious* è un classico esempio).

Comment: Anche qualcosa di esagerato può far ridere. *A: Un caffè e una brioche. B: 20 euro, prego. A: 20 euro? E' ridicolo!*. Oppure: *Queste scarpe costano una somma ridicola: 500 euro, non mi faccia ridere!*. In entrambi questi casi io non ho problemi ad interpretare la frase.

Comment: @Nico. Non ho problemi nemmeno io ad interpretare le frasi indicate, tuttavia nel primo caso "ridicolo" si riferisce al soggetto sottinteso ("ciò", "questo") ed è più o meno sinonimo di "assurdo", mentre nel secondo contesto personalmente non userei l'aggettivo "ridicolo", che mi sembra una scelta bizzarra.

Comment: @Paola: non so, l'uso di ridicolo nella seconda frase non mi sconvolge. Probabilmene parlo troppo nella lingua d'Albione... :)

Comment: Se l'aggettivo "ridicolo" è usato in una frase ironica non dovresti ottenere esattamente l'effetto della versione inglese?

Comment: @Bakuriu. Penso di sì, ma il contesto non era ironico nel film (ho trovato una delle scene in cui si usa l'aggettivo, ma purtroppo è in inglese... dal minuto 3.26 a 3.32 circa http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUQaeuqlqr4

Answer (score 6):

> A questo punto mi sorge spontanea la domanda: si tratta dell'ennesimo
>   caso in cui, per seguire l'inglese, abbiamo coniato un'espressione
>   "italiana" che italiana non è?

Non mi sembra affatto che quel significato di "ridiculous" (*ridiculous amount* = quantità enorme) sia entrato in uso nella lingua italiana. Uno stipendio "ridicolo" continua a significare uno stipendio molto basso. Chiuderei il caso parlando di un inglesismo nel doppiaggio italiano.

Comment: Il problema è che siamo molto "permeabili": se un errore di traduzione viene ripetuto molte volte, specie nei film, ha la tendenza a filtrare nella lingua. Non escluderei che anche "ridicolo" subisca in futuro questo trattamento, per ora secondo me è ancora percepito come sbagliato. Una buona traduzione sarebbe stata "una cifra pazzesca", che non è ambigua e mantiene il riferimento a qualcosa di così esagerato da essere buffo.

Answer (score 2):

I am re-editing my answer to reply to other users comments.

In order to clarify whether or not the usage of "ridicolo" as synonym of "eccessivo" is acceptable in Italian language, we first need to check its usual meanings.

According to [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ridicolo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29), these are:

> «1. [che fa ridere, degno di riso o di derisione: crede di essere originale e invece è soltanto r.] ≈ (non com.) arlecchinesco, buffo, comico, da ridere, macchiettistico, operettistico, (lett.) ridevole, risibile, tutto da ridere. ↔ grave, serio. 2. (estens.) [di scarsa entità o valore: mi è costato una somma r.] ≈ (non com.) derisorio, esiguo, irrisorio. ↑ insignificante. ↔ cospicuo, non indifferente, notevole, ragguardevole, rilevante.»

According to [HomoLaicus](http://www.homolaicus.com/linguaggi/sinonimi/hypertext/1290.htm):

> «buffo, buffonesco, comico, esiguo, goffo, misero, piccolo, assurdo, cretino, bassissimo, squallido, insignificante, meschino, inesistente, illogico, insensato, irragionevole, irrisorio, burlesco, spropositato, minimo, risibile, ridevole, macchiettistico || Vedi anche:  farsesco, pagliaccesco, ridanciano, divertente, esilarante, spassoso, umoristico, inconsistente, insensibile, trascurabile, inelegante, sgraziato, irrilevante, magro, povero, scarso, spelacchiato, stentato, stento, stiracchiato, stitico, pidocchioso, avaro, basso, gramo, microscopico, misurato, modesto, ridotto, sparuto, pacchiano, plebeo, volgare, allegro, anonimo, banale, grigio, piatto, vuoto, arido, borghese, ignobile, minuscolo, miserabile, nano, patetico, piccino, pietoso, sciagurato, umile, assente, fantasma, ideale, immaginario, contraddittorio, folle, pazzo, cieco, duro, irresponsabile, corto, mediocre, poco, curioso, deficiente, fesso, imbecille, scemo, sciocco, stupido, tardo, eccessivo, enorme, favoloso, gigantesco, incredibile, pauroso, essenziale, grottesco, impossibile, infantile Contrari:  congruo, considerevole, consistente, forte, grande, importante, ricco, funereo, lugubre, logico, ragionevole, rispettabile || V. anche  notevole, ragguardevole, rilevante, sensibile, significativo, sostanzioso, tangibile, ingente, abbondante, cospicuo, solido, determinante, apprezzabile, copioso, dovizioso, rimarchevole, grosso».

It is clear that in Italian "una cifra ridicola" is typically interpreted as "a ridicolously small quantity". Nonetheless it is clear from the context that its meaning, in the movie, is the opposite, i.e. "a ridicolously excessive quantity". In linguistics, this is called an [antiphrasis](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/antifrasi_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) and, as such, it is accepted by default and we do not need any prior example: you can do it if you want to, no need to ask anyone's permission, the only limit is that the receiver of your message must be able to follow you. Exactly as happens for other [words or expressions](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pauroso_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29) such as "terribile", "pauroso", "allucinante", "bestiale", "da paura", "da urlo", "pazzesco", "spaventoso", "tremendo", "mostruoso", etc. The beauty of an antiphrasis is that it requires an increased attention level on the receiver's side.

It is certainly possible that this kind of antiphrases is particularly popular in American English - so what? *An antiphrasis is an antiphrasis is an antiphrasis is an antiphrasis* ([cit.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose)).

It is also possible that a proper [`semantic change`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) is occurring in this particular case: we have a reversal of the original meaning of the word from a negative to a positive connotation, so the process would be called `amelioration`.

@Paola You can find it hard to assign "terribile" and "pauroso" ameliorative meanings, but that's what has been happening for many years now. I can give you [many](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pauroso_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29) [examples](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_sinonimi_contrari/P/pauroso.shtml) (Corriere: « … incredibile, straordinario, eccezionale, insolito, prodigioso …»; Treccani: « … 3. (fam., iperb.) [che si distingue per eccezionalità: ha un'intelligenza p.] ≈ (fam.) allucinante, (fam.) bestiale, (gerg., iperb.) da paura, (gerg.) da urlo, eccezionale, fantastico, fenomenale, grandioso, (fam., iperb.) pazzesco, (fam.) spaventoso, spropositato, straordinario, strepitoso, stupefacente, (fam.) tremendo …») - the point is: will you still find that hard?

Comment: I wonder... I tried the sentence on many people (native speakers) and none of them interpreted the adjective in any other way than in the usual negative meaning. As a matter of fact, I find it hard to give the adjectives "terribile" and "pauroso" a positive connotation, and in fact the links you provide indicate hyperboles, not so much "something particularly good" (when would you consider the sentence "Sei di una ignoranza *paurosa*" positive?). I'm afraid you are just stretching the line.

Comment: -1: this does not answer the question, which is about the word *ridicolo*, not about *pauroso* or *terribile*. Just because *pauroso* (o *da paura*) can be used in certain contexts to mean *great* that does not mean the same works for *ridicolo* too (note: I am not saying that it could not be used in that way, but this answer does not give any proof to that effect).

Comment: like it much more like this :)

Answer (score 0):

> A questo punto mi sorge spontanea la domanda: si tratta dell'ennesimo caso in cui, per seguire l'inglese, abbiamo coniato un'espressione "italiana" che italiana non è?

D'accordo al 100%. L'interpretazione della traduzione non è corretta.

Per esempio, usando la frase:
**Have you seen that truck with ridiculous tyres?**

e cercando di tradurla allo stesso modo:
**Hai visto quel camion con le ruote ridicole?**

Effettivamente, se letta in italiano, non rivela per niente che il camion ha delle ruote fuori misura.